# Importing a locally downloaded pdfjs library

Tags: javascript, html, github, jspdf

I have so far been unable to import the code required to utilize pdf.js into my script. At first including

```
<script src="node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js"></script>
```

was enough to get it to run, and I could access a variable called "pdfjsLib" for everything I needed. Now that I uploaded the code to GitHub pages, it doesn't recognize the variable even though all files are present. I think I need a way to import it, but every option I have come across has failed.

```
import pdfjsLib from "/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js";
```

Fails

```
var pdfjsLib = window['node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js'];
```

Fails

Here is the link to the repository, but I don't think that it is required to solve this seemingly simple problem. https://github.com/SlayerOfWhales/CurseOfAether

Comment: What are the failing tracebacks that you have encoutered?

Comment: #1Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

Comment: #2
Simply returns undefined

Comment: Have you tried to do something like:

`import {pdfjsLib} from "/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js"; `

?

Comment: No export of that name

Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.js' does not provide an export named 'pdfjsLib'

Comment: Have you considered creating an `index.js` at `/node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build` to export `pdf.js` as `pdfjsLib`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235057/discussion-between-slayer-of-whales-and-lucascavalcante).